# Can't install ADT Plugin on Eclipse Helios

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I read somewhere (cannot remember from where but I think from stackoverflow) that the best eclipse version for making android apps is the Eclipse Helios 3.6.2 or higher. So I downloaded it (3.6.2 version) but when I trying to install the adt plugin, all go smooth until this error:

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Haven't seen that one before. Can you install other plugins alright? First thing I'd try is a fresh workspace, followed by a fresh download of the latest Eclipse.

Comment: The eclipse that I downloaded didn't need install, i just unzip it and run the exe file... Maybe this is the problem? Can you give me a good link?

Comment: Nope, that's how it comes. Eclipse doesn't have an installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this problem when I have installed java 1.7 in the system. Then I got this message with any version of the eclipse. Therefore make sure you have installed only java 1.6 and if you are using Windows make sure that the environment path doesn't contain any reference to java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse versions earlier than 3.7.2 have issues running in Java 7.  You either have to use a newer Eclipse version or run the version you have with an older JRE.